# When using Chrome Sync, if i have two user accounts open, why cant i close down one?

Tags: google-chrome, google-sync

If i have two user accounts open via Chrome Sync, is there anyway for me to close the window of one user account yet still saving the open tabs, so that when i open that particular user account the tabs reopen.

I have tried doing this and it doesn't work. Does this mean that syncing will only work if i quit the whole of Chrome down??

Answer (score 0):

Editing this because I misunderstood your question.  There are a few extensions/plugins em that will allow you to save all of your tabs and sessions to reopen later.  That might be a suitable workaround at least.

The open tabs sync  between browser installations when you close chrome altogether.  Simply closing a window when another is open is treated the same as closing all the tabs in that window and leaving the others open.

<strike>Also the window doesn't really belong to either account.  Multiple accounts means both will be logged in simultaneously and share much of the resources.</strike>

Looks like I'm wrong about that last part; although my experience seemed to indicate otherwise.  But here's what google says about it:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im going to address each of your paragraphs in turn: 1. Thanks i will probably use this option 2. So the open tabs sync works when chrome opens and closes, rather than during a chrome session, ok got it. 3. I dont think this is correct; I think there is a degree of separation between accounts, surely?

Comment: Hmm see my edit above, I think I was inaccurate.  My experience with multiple signins on chrome was kind of a mess in reality.